# Can't understand pointer's mem address result in C

Tags: c, pointers

I'm experiencing a mind-blowing doubt concerning the use of pointers in C. So, I've searched a lot about this, but no satisfatory answer was presented to me. Here is the thing:

I declare a pointer of type INT, and a variable of type INT (e.g int x, *pointer). So, let's suppose that both of them occupy sequential addresses in RAM, like 0x102 and 0x106, respectively. No surprises so far. Then, I declare x = 5. My memory map should be like this, shouldn't?

```
int x, *pointer;
x = 5;
```

[image: pointer1]

Ok. In the college I learned to assign a pointer this way:

```
pointer = &x;
```

And my memory map should be like this:

[image: pointer2]

So far so good. But the question is: if, instead of above, I assign a pointer like this:

```
*pointer = x;
```

The memory address of 'x' shouldn't be stored in the pointer's memory address? I always wondered something like the "Memory Map 2", but the result is the same of the "Memory Map 1", that is, the 0x106 address holds a garbage number. So how the program KNOWS where I'd like to point to, if the memory address of 'x' isn't stored at pointer's memory address? Where this information is stored?

It looks like a simple question, but I can't understand. :(

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Getting how pointers work is tricky. Here's something that might help.

You wrote

```
int x, *pointer;
```

which is not just idiomatic; this is telling you something important. It is telling you that the expression `x` is *a variable that can hold an integer*; that is hopefully clear. It is also telling you that the expression `*pointer` is *also a variable that can hold an integer*.

When you say

```
x = 123;
```

that means "store the value `123` in the variable `x`".

And so when you say

```
*pointer = 456;
```

that means "store the value `456` in the variable `*pointer`".

When you say

```
pointer = &x;
```

that means "the expression `*pointer` -- which remember is a variable that can hold an integer -- is the same variable as `x`". They are *aliases* -- two names for the same variable.

So your question is:

> How does the program know where I'd like to point to, if the memory address of `x` isn't stored at pointer's memory address?

Let me rephrase that question using the terminology I've established:

> How does the program know *which variable* `*pointer` refers to if I do not initialize `pointer`?

**It does not know.**  If you say:

```
int x;
printf("%d", x);
```

then you can get *any* integer printed; this is undefined behavior. You haven't said what value you want the variable `x` to have, so it can have any value.  When you say:

```
int *pointer;
*pointer = 123;
```

Then you are saying "store `123` in variable `*pointer`", but you haven't said what variable `*pointer` is. So, just as `x` can have any value, `*pointer` can be *any variable*. Again, we have undefined behavior.

Is that now clear?

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. So, to make sure that I understood what you said, let me have another example:

`int x, *pointer;`
`pointer = (int *)malloc(sizeof(pointer));`

By definition, if I printf("%d", *pointer), this instruction should print the content of the address contained inside &pointer, that is, garbage, right?

Comment: My doubt came when I tried to do this: *pointer = 5 (for instance). IMO, I should get an error, because I was trying to put the value '5' in the memory address contained inside &pointer. Instead, the code works out with no warnings in "Code Blocks" (I expected a segmentation fault) . Am I wrong to think about pointers this way? My primary definition of pointer is wrong?

Thanks in advance for the help! :)

Comment: @user2373016: "undefined behavior" means that **anything can happen**. A seg fault is included in "anything". **So is no seg fault**. The system is not *required* to give you a seg fault when you do something wrong; rather, **you are required to do everything right**.

Comment: @user2373016: As for whether your "primary definition" is wrong, I don't know because I don't know what it is. I encourage you to think about pointers the way I do; a pointer is something that when you put a `*` in front of it, gives you a *variable* -- a location that you can store something. Everything else -- all this stuff about pointers being memory addresses and whatnot -- is an implementation detail that you can ignore. A pointer need not be an address, all it needs to be is something that gives you a variable when you dereference it.

Comment: Lipert: Thanks again for the hand! I got it. [ ]'s

Answer (score 4):

```
int x, *pointer;
*pointer = x;
```

This is undefined behaviour, because `pointer` does not point to a valid memory location.

```
int x, *pointer;
x = 5;
pointer = &x;
*pointer = x;
```

The last line of this is basically the same as `x = x`, because `pointer` points to `x`;

Answer (score 3):

Since `*` is the dereference operator, then you will try to:

- store the **value** of `x` (since there's no addressof, `&` operator before its name)
- to the **memory pointed to by** `pointer` (and **not** into the pointer itself, which wouldn't make sense anyway), which is indeterminate, since your pointer hasn't yet been initialized.

This is not storing the address of `x` into `pointer`; what you want is achieved solely by writing `pointer = &x;`, nothing else will do that. By the way, because of the assignment to the memory pointed to by an uninitialized pointer, `*pointer = x` invokes **undefined behavior.**

Answer (score 2):

Doing

`*somePtr = someVar`

assigns the value of `somevar` in the place pointed by `somePtr` ..

To be more comprehensive,

```
int x = 2, y =3;
int * pointer;
pointer = &x;
*pointer = y;
```

asiigns the value of `y` in `x` . That's it!